# Passing mocked methods to mount/shallowMount using Vue Test Utils

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, vue-test-utils

Can somebody please explain to me why a mocked function passed in a `methods` object to `shallowMount` can not be accessed in the test through the wrapper object and instead must be accessed by first creating a variable as a reference to the mocked function?

I have tried mount and shallowMount, created/mounted hooks and also by calling the function directly as opposed to inside the created/mounted hook.

```
// TestComponent.spec.js

import TestComponent from '@/components/TestComponent'
import { shallowMount, createLocalVue } from '@vue/test-utils'

const localVue = createLocalVue()

const setLoadingMock = jest.fn() // mock function that is accessible in the test

function createWrapper () {

  const defaultMountingOptions = {
    localVue,
    methods: {
      setLoading: setLoadingMock
    }
  }

  return shallowMount(TestComponent, defaultMountingOptions)
}

describe('TestComponent.vue', () => {

  let wrapper

  beforeEach(() => {
    wrapper = createWrapper()
  });

  it('will call setLoading', () => {
    expect(wrapper.vm.setLoading).toHaveBeenCalled() 
    // FAILS. Console message:
    // Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

    // Received has type:  function
    // Received has value: [Function bound mockConstructor]
  })

  it('will call setLoading', () => {
    expect(setLoadingMock).toHaveBeenCalled() // PASSES
  })
})
```

```
TestComponent.vue

export default {
  name: 'TestComponent',
  mounted () {
    this.setLoading()
  },

  methods: {
    setLoading () {
      console.log('Original method'); // Never logs
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I got the same issue if I replace `setLoading: setLoadingMock` by `setLoading: () => {}`

Answer (score 2):

`mount` or `shallowMount` are not important in this case. `mount` means test will mount component and its child components, while `shallowMount` will mount only component and stub its child components.

You are mocking the `setLoading` method, which means that you are replacing the original method with a mock. Meaning, when `setLoading` method is called, it won't run the code from your component, but code from the test mock - in this case `jest.fn()`.

Purpose of mocking is to check if the mocked method was called correctly.

Also, `wrapper.vm.setLoading` calls the `setLoading` method.

Comment: If I replace `setLoading: setLoadingMock` by `setLoading: () => {}` I get the same error message as above if I run: `expect(wrapper.vm.setLoading).toBeCalled()`. Maybe you know how to overcome this ?

Answer (score 2):

Instead of referencing the wrapper instance, you should spy the method, e.g.:

```
const setLoading = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm, 'setLoading');
expect(setLoading).toHaveBeenCalled() ;
```